# How to call astro API endpoint form client side

Tags: astrojs

I want to create API route in astro which can be called from the client side.

Is there any way that I can create such API point like express inside astro?

I call this "/api/aws_presigned_img_upload" endpoint from the client side

```js
async uploadByFile(file) {
    console.log({
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type,
    });
    //get presigned url from server
    let presignedUrl = await fetch(
        "/api/aws_presigned_img_upload",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                filename: file.name,
                filetype: file.type,
            }),
        },
    );
}
```

But astro doesn't work

Comment: Hi did you resolve this? I having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

This only works when you do have enabled the

SSR, and only supported on such a platforms support hosting SSR

Like Vercel, CloudFlare Pages, more

So all you have to do is to create an api directory within /src/pages

here you can write any ts,js code that will considered as an API and it works upon the requests

and it should follow a guidelines of code like nextjs
here's an example
https://github.com/zjunior-infra/zJunior/blob/main/src/pages/api/report.ts

and here's the documentation
https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/#server-endpoints-api-routes